# AngularJS $index inside ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-switch

I am trying to access `$index` of `ng-repeat` and place it inside `ng-switch-when`. [Here is the last thing I have tried](http://jsfiddle.net/aLDJJ/1721/). Small piece of what I am trying to do:

```
<li ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-switch on="MenuSelected">
 <span ng-switch-when="$index">{{ contact }} {{$index}}</span>
</li>
```

`MenuSelected` I have define in my controller with 0 for example, and I have 2 contacts for test. I have tried to mix `ng` things in different tags and everything fall (just show lines), so I don't think that is the problem. When I remove `$index` and place for example 0 everything show up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot use expressions with `ngSwitch`

refrer this [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the string "someVal" not against the value of the expression $scope.someVal

this implies that `ng-switch-when="$index"` `$index` is treated as a string not as a index value

---

**use ngIf instead**

```
    <span ng-if="$index == MenuSelected">{{ contact }} {{$index}}</span>
```

here is the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aLDJJ/1722/)

Comment: yes its saying you are not allowed to use expressions